# Generating family of demicube graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, polyhedra

I've been using the built-ins `HypercubeGraph[n]` and `TuranGraph[2 n, n]` to explore properties of the $1$-skeletons of the $n$-[hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) and $n$-[orthoplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope), respectively. I'd like to expand this search to the $n$-[demihypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demihypercube) (a.k.a. the [halved cube](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HalvedCubeGraph.html)). Is there a built-in for the demihypercube graph? Or is there a sensible way to modify the `HypercubeGraph` to get the demihypercube graph?

If we think of the hypercube as being the convex hull of $\{0,1\}^n$, the demihypercube is the convex hull of $$\{(b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n) \in \{0, 1\}^n 
 \mid b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n \text{ is even} \}.$$

---

(I'm a quite new Mathematica user—mostly I just use built-ins to compute simple things for the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/).)

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question; I'm willing to offer a 100 rep bounty to anyone who can answer this.

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HalvedCubeGraph.html

Comment: According to MathWorld, you could just do `DemicubeGraph[n_Integer?Positive] := GraphPower[HypercubeGraph[n - 1], 2]`, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat anticlimactically, it turns out [the corresponding notebook](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/GraphTheory/HalvedCubeGraph.nb) in the MathWorld entry already shows a lot of ways.

For instance, `"HalvedCube"` is already known to `GraphData[]`:

```
Table[GraphData[{"HalvedCube", k}], {k, 7}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: demicube graphs]

Otherwise, there are a bunch of alternative definitions, e.g.

```
DemicubeGraph[n_Integer?Positive] := GraphPower[HypercubeGraph[n - 1], 2]

DemicubeGraph[5]
```

[image: 5-demicube graph]

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[%, GraphComplement[GraphData["ClebschGraph"]]]
   True
```

or

```
HalvedCubeGraph[n_, opts___] := Module[{dom = Tuples[{0, 1}, {n - 1}], edges},
      edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ Select[Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 2^(n - 1)},
                                                      {j, i, 2^(n - 1)}], 1],
                                        0 < HammingDistance @@ dom[[#]] <= 2 &];
      Graph[Range[2^(n - 1)], edges, opts]]

HalvedCubeGraph[4]
```

[image: 4-demicube graph]

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[%, GraphData["SixteenCellGraph"]]
   True
```

Comment: Perhaps anticlimactic, but it's just what I was looking for. Thanks!